# Why does this code return the results that it does

Tags: javascript

When I run this in node I get the following result. Why?

```
//Why does this code return the results that it does?
function isBig(thing) {
  if (thing == 0 || thing == 1 || thing == 2) {
    return false
  }
  return true
}
isBig(1)    // false
isBig([2])  // false
isBig([3])  // true
```

Comment: `console.log([1,2].toString()=="1,2")`

Comment: Look at this [equality-comparison ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: [Annotated ES5 -> 11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5)

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator in JavaScript converts its operands into a common type before checking for equality (that's why it is recommended always to use the `===` operator, which respects the types).
In your case the common type is `number`, so the each given array is converted into a number. For a single element array the conversion into a number results in the single element (converted to a number).

The parameter `[2]` equals the number 2, so return `false`.
`[3]` on the other hand does neither equal 0, 1, or 2, so return `true`.

See also https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares equity loosely.

To quote [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

> Loose equality compares two values for equality, after converting both values to a common type.

This means that `[2] == 2` is `true` it also means `"2" == 2` is `true`

and it's why it is so often recommended to use strict equality so that `[2] === 2` is `false` unless you are really looking for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

To piggy back on what Mark_M said when you pass the [2] and [3] to the function it's treating them as object literals instead of numbers. Then in your function call its typecasting them for the comparison.

```js
console.log(typeof(1));
console.log(typeof[2]);
console.log(typeof[3]);
```